# Clickable and hover menu css

Tags: html, css

So I want a dropdown menu but instead of it pop up in left, it will pop up down without overlay other subtopics and so these other subtopics will float to bot.
I made this montage on paint so you can see what I want:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfHKM.jpg)

```css
nav ul {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px  whitesmoke;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #FB030F;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width:calc(100% - 3px);
  
}

nav > ul > li ul  {
  display: none;
}

nav ul > li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}


nav #m {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
}

nav #m:hover {
  background-color: #ff7373;
}

nav > ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
ul li:hover > #n {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

nav a {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="builds.html" id="m">Builds</a>
        <ul id="n">
          <li><a href="build1.html" id="m">Build 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="build2.html" id="m">Build 2</a></li >
          <li><a href="build3.html" id="m">Build 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="build4.html" id="m">Build 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="build5.html" id="m">Build 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="build6.html" id="m">Build 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="build7.html" id="m">Build 7</a></li>
          <li><a href="build8.html" id="m">Build 8</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="configurador.html" id="m">Configurador</a></li>
      <li><a href="info.html" id="m">Componentes</a></li>
      <li><a href="help.html" id="m">Guia</a></li>
    </ul></li>


</nav>
```

Let me just write something here so I can post this question, because stack overflow is telling me that I cannot post this because I have too much code and so I have to add more details. But I guess my doubt is simple and I do not need to add more info, if I am wrong tell me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, then try this:

```
nav ul {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px  whitesmoke;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #FB030F;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width:calc(100% - 3px);
}

nav > ul > li ul  {
  display: none;
}

nav ul > li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}


nav #m {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
}

nav #m:hover {
  background-color: #ff7373;
}

nav > ul > li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

nav a {
  text-align: center;
}
```

I just deleted some classes which positioned blocks absolute, that's why menu appeared not where you wanted.
Hope it'll help.